# CUDA: nvcc cannot be detected though installed

Tags: build, cuda, gpu, ubuntu-14.04, nvcc

I successfully installed CUDA 7.0 on ubuntu(ami instance), but when I typed 'nvcc -version', it told me that

```
The program 'nvcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
You will have to enable the component called 'multiverse'
```

That's weird since the installation was successful in /usr/local and I've added CUDA 7.0 to my path. I've also tried rebooting my instance then typing in the same command and it didn't work. I'm also sure that the driver for my GPU is correctly. (same error occurs when I use theano to run nvcc test)

Comment: can you find where nvcc is located in your filesystem? If you can, is that location really in your $PATH?

Comment: can you please post the result of the following command: `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Sorry, I just found out that I didn't actually add cuda to my current user's path. Now that the problem has been fixed

Comment: @YiqunLiu: Please add your solution as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 21):

Actually, it's the case that I set environment variable in a wrong way.
Instead of using

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin:$PATH
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

as it's recommended, I choose to edit /etc/profile, which is not recommended.

Comment: The PATH variable resets once the terminal window is closed. To permanently set the PATH variable: (1) Run the command `gedit ~/.profile`, (2) Add the line `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin` to the bottom and save, (3) Log out and log in again.